# Extract data dynamically in Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

This is the sample data in the column. I want to extract the values only associated with 5 in dynamically.

```
'{"2113":5,"2112":5,"2114":4,"2511":5}'
```

The final structure should be 3 rows of names and values?

I tried with JSON extract function but that not help. Thanks

Final result i want,

```
  value | Key
  2113     5
  2112     5
  2115     5
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the output you would want from this input data.

Comment: Will there only ever be these values (2113, 2112, 2114, 2511) in the JSON? Will the number of output rows desired potentially change (eg just 1, or all 4, or maybe even many more values)? This looks like something that is best done in an ETL process _before_ loading the data into Redshift. Although, I wonder whether a Stored Procedure might be suitable?

Comment: Yes, we don't know about the values inside the array It will be increased based on new item generation.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the output you would want from this input data.

Comment: Edited the question for output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved the result using multiple splits.

```
`SELECT  distinct split_part(split_part(replace(replace(replace(json_field,'{',''),'}',''),'"',''),',',i),': ',1) as value,` `split_part(split_part(replace(replace(replace(json_field,'{',''),'}',''),'"',''),',',i),':',2) as key FROM table
  JOIN schema.seq_1_to_100 as numbers
  ON i <=regexp_count(json_field,':') `
```

Answer (score 0):

So, what you need to do is to unnest the json object (have a key-value pair per row). Unnesting in Readshift is tricky. One needs a sequence table, and then perfom a `CROSS JOIN` with proper filter condition. Usually unnesting is done on an array, and then it's easier, since indicies are easy to generate. To unnest a key-value map (JSON object) one needs to know all the keys (Redshift cannot do it). Your example is lucky, since the keys are integers and they're cardinality is relatively low.

This is a sketched out solution. Please note that you will have to change the way the sequence table is created:

```
WITH input(json) AS (
    SELECT '{"2113":5,"2112":5,"2114":4,"2511":5}'::varchar
)
   , sequence(idx) AS (
    -- instead of the below you should use sequence table
    SELECT 2113
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2112
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2114
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2511
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2512
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2513
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2514
)
   , unnested(key, val) AS (
    SELECT idx::varchar                      as key,
           json_extract_path_text(json, key) as val
    FROM input
             CROSS JOIN sequence
    WHERE val IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT *
FROM unnested
WHERE val = 5


key  | val 
2113 | 5 
2112 | 5 
2511 | 5
```

---

how to generate a large sequence in Redshift:

```
...
sequence(idx) AS (
    SELECT row_number() OVER () 
    FROM arbitrary_table_having_enough_rows
    limit 10000 
)
...
```

Other option is to have a specialized sequence table - here there's an idea on how to do it http://www.silota.com/docs/recipes/redshift-sequential-generate-series-numbers-time.html

Comment: Great idea!! but It's taking too much time to complete in Redshift When joining with the sequence.

Comment: Achived the result reference from your query.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative (which in my opinion: Better) is to use the native `UNPIVOT` syntax of Redshift. Reference: https://bambooengineering.io/unnest-json-objects-in-redshift/

Input:

```
[
{"shop_id":10, "apple_count": 2},
{"shop_id":10, "orange_count": 6}
]
```

SQL:

```
SELECT shop_id, key, value
FROM example_data ed, UNPIVOT ed.inventory AS value AT key
```

Output:

```
+-----------+--------------+---------+
| shop_id   | key          | value   |
|-----------+--------------+---------|
| 10        | apple_count  | 2       |
| 10        | orange_count | 6       |
+-----------+--------------+---------+
```